# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Hi I have tensorflow installed of version 1.14.0 on my ubuntu machine. I am trying to run a code with

```
import keras
```

and I get an error

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'backend'
```

i have tried installing specific version of keras(2.0.8) because i have seen an answer which says keras 2.0.8 is required for tensorflow 1.14.0 . But still I get the error.

Can someone help me with this. Really stuck at a vey basic point

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple versions of keras installed? Did you try reinstalling? Sorry for posting as awnser but I don't have enough reputation to comment

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion